# When is a sacrifice bunt a statistically "good" option?

Tags: baseball, statistics, sabermetrics

In the past several years the sacrifice bunt has come under fire as a "waste of an at bat" and "lowering your chance to score." No one denies that outs are very valuable in baseball, but is it ever a good idea to intentionally give up an out to advance a runner (or runners)?

I am more interested in cases where the pitcher is not at bat.

Comment: first person to quote "the book" wins a gold star :)

Comment: Just ordered "The Book" on amazon, can't wait for it to arrive!

Answer (score 8):

According to the calculations done in this [James Click article](http://www.baseballprospectus.com/article.php?articleid=2844) titled "Taking One for the Team: When Does it Make Sense to Sacrifice? Part 1", he concludes:

> Thus, we can conclude that, in this simple case, no matter who is
>   coming up next, any batter hitting below .075 should always sacrifice,
>   while any batter hitting better than .243 should never sacrifice. If
>   nothing else, this conclusion lends further credibility to the idea
>   that pitchers should almost always sacrifice if given the opportunity.

In the [second part](http://www.baseballprospectus.com/article.php?articleid=2851) of his series, he notes:

> Finally, we need to consider that sacrificing is a strategy often
>   employed when getting one run is more important to winning than
>   scoring many.

and

> The values in Situation 3 immediately stand out. Virtually every major
>   leaguer is under those numbers; so, according to this model, it is
>   almost ALWAYS a good idea to sacrifice in that situation if only one
>   run is needed. This conclusion flies in the face of many of the
>   conventions usually espoused by performance analysts, but it is
>   supported by the raw numbers from the run probability table. Notice
>   that the probability of scoring at least one run increases from .635
>   to .693 when sacrificing in Situation 3.

**Note**: Situation 3 is a man on 2nd with no outs.

He concludes in [part 3](http://www.baseballprospectus.com/article.php?articleid=2869) of the series:

> Therefore, in the broadest conclusion possible, we can say that
>   sacrificing is a good idea when pitchers are batting and, for most of
>   the hitters in the league, when there is a man on second, no one out,
>   and a single run is the goal. Even then, there is a set of the
>   league's best hitters who should never lay down a bunt; which is too
>   bad, because it would be fun to see Bonds square around, just once.

So the final conclusion that he draws is that a sacrifice bunt makes sense only in one situation: man on second, no one out, and a single run is the goal.